# simple way of making selected navigation page link change colour?

Tags: html, css

I know this is a silly question but for some reason I'm always having a problem with changing the background colour of a selected navigation item, I looked this up so many times and I tried doing the selected classes for a button but for some reason it doesn't work for me, can someone point out what am I doing wrong?

html:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="selected" href="?page=home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=work">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=shop">Shop</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
#nav {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;
    height:52px;
    background-color: #000; opacity: 0.7; filter: alpha(opacity=50);


}

#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;  
    padding-left: 650px;

}

#nav li {
    margin: 0px;
   display: inline-block;
}

#nav li a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;

}

#nav li a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: #999;
    background-color: #666;
    color: white;
}
li.selected a { background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: the `selected` class is not on the `li`, change that to `li a.selected`

Answer (score 2):

You've two issues here.

1. You are using `li.selected a` but you are assigning your `class` to `a` tag so the selector should be `li a.selected`
2. Specificity. You have `#nav` in all the selectors, since ID selectors are more specific, you need to add it to your `.active` selector as well. So it should be `#nav li a.selected`

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/fvrdtzxt/)

---

*Suggestion* :

I would recommend you to use `class` instead of `id`. Keep ID's for JavaScript selectors, as it can access your DOM faster, but for CSS, stick to classes as much as you can, else you will end up with long specific selectors and even `!important`.

So you should have something like `<div id="nav" class="nav">` and use `.nav` in CSS instead of `#nav`